# .NET 6 attach to windows session switch

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am migration an app from .NET Framework to .NET 6. It starts Kestrel web server internally and it is intended to run as a Windows Service -  in the old version that was achieved using [Topshelf library](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf), so I continued using it. One of the requirements is to listen for session switch events and send messages to third-party application.

In the *old version* of the application it was achieved again with the help of Topshelf. However, in the callback there was used static DI container to get access to services:

```cs
return HostFactory.New((hostConfigurator) =>
{
    // ...
    hostConfigurator.EnableSessionChanged(); 
    hostConfigurator.Service<WindowService>((serviceConfigurator) =>
    {
        serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(hostSettings => new WindowService());
    // ...
    serviceConfigurator
            .WhenSessionChanged((serviceHelper, arguments) => serviceHelper.SessionChange(arguments));
    // ...
    });

    // ...
});
```

And this is the callback:

```cs
private void SessionChange(SessionChangedArguments changeDescription)
{
    var sessionService =
        DependencyInjectionContainer.GetRequiredService<IUserSessionMonitoringService>();
        
    if (sessionService == null)
    {
        LOG.Warning(...);
        return;
    }
              
    sessionService.SessionChanged(...);
}
```

So, here's the problem: in the callback a static `DependencyInjectionContainer` class is used to get the needed service/s. However in the new version of the app this approach won't work as this static class was abandoned. Also, I don't even have access to built-in .NET DI Container, because during the time the Topshelf is configured, the container isn't build.

As further steps I investigated what is Topshelf using under the hood for this functionality - that's [SystemEvents.SessinSwitch event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). I tried to attach an event handler to it from a hosted service, in which the needed services are injected. For the sake of the test, I just wanted to log some text in a file from the event handler. However, when sign out/in there's nothing in the file from those logs.

```
public class SystemSessionMonitoringHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IUserSessionMonitoringService userSessionMonitoring;
    private readonly ILogger<SystemSessionMonitoringHostedService> logger;

    public SystemSessionMonitoringHostedService(
        IUserSessionMonitoringService userSessionMonitoring,
        ILogger<SystemSessionMonitoringHostedService> logger)
    {
        this.userSessionMonitoring = userSessionMonitoring;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += OnSessionChanged;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    } 

    private void OnSessionChanged(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs eventArgs)
    { 
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventArgs);
        logger.LogCritical($"Object: {json}"); 
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if those `SystemEvents` works in .NET Core/5+? Am I missing something? Suggestions for workarounds are also welcome.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. TopShelf itself is no longer maintained [and the Github repo was archived](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf). The code you posted uses the DI container as a service locator instead of letting the container inject dependencies.  You can check [Create a Windows Service using BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) to see how to create a Windows Service in .NET Core

Comment: You can start by creating a new Worker project. This will take care of the boilerplate code needed to create the host, DI, configuration, logging etc, although this is just a few lines in .NET (Core) 6. The service (Worker) class itself inherits from `BackgroundService`, not just `IHostedService`. That's mainly for convenience. `I don't even have access to built-in .NET DI Container` you don't need it, the Dependency (service) is Injected through a constructor parameter

Comment: Could you please show real [mre] of your attempt "I tried to attach an event handler to it from a hosted service" (including "a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually" part you linked to)? It is not exactly useful to see old code.